# Create a list of items after every iteration in python

Tags: python

My goal is to capture the intersection of the items in the lists below (`j` and `k`) into three separate lists.

```
j=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4,],[2,1,3]]
k=[[2,4,5],[3,2,1,][4,5,6]]
```

My attempt:

```
>>> b=[]
>>> for x in j:
    for y in k:
        c=[h for h in x if h in y]
            b.append(c)
```

output:

```
>>> b
[[2], [1, 2, 3], [], [2, 4], [2, 3], [4], [2], [2, 1, 3], []]
```

Desired output:

```
[[[2], [1, 2, 3], []], [[2, 4], [2, 3], [4]], [[2], [2, 1, 3], []]]
```

Comment: You don't really want to be using single-letter variable names in real programs, unless they are nothing more than quick throwaway variables like index counters (and you don't need those often in Python). But I guess this is just a simplified example, right?

Comment: yea Tim, its just a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an inner list:

```
>>> b = []
>>> for x in j:
...     inner = []
...     for y in k:
...         c = [h for h in x if h in y]
...         inner.append(c)
...     b.append(inner)
...
>>> b
[[[2], [1, 2, 3], []], [[2, 4], [2, 3], [4]], [[2], [2, 1, 3], []]]
```

or (shudder) a nested [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> b = [[[h for h in x if h in y] for y in k] for x in j]
>>> b
[[[2], [1, 2, 3], []], [[2, 4], [2, 3], [4]], [[2], [2, 1, 3], []]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about sets and itertools.  I left the type conversions in-line to better show the idea. Ideally you won't call set() for every combinations yielded by itertools.product(), but just as an idea:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

j=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,1,3]]
k=[[2,4,5],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x,y in itertools.product(j,k):
    d[tuple(x)].append( list( set(x) & set(y) ) )
print d.values()
```